# If Click on the type datepicker the dates going infinity how can i select the dates manually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd, daterangepicker

```
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';
import { useState } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import React from 'react';
import { Select } from 'antd';

const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;
const { Option } = Select;

function Filter() {

    const [filterType, setFilterType] = useState('None');
    const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState();
    const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);

    const handleFilterType = (value) => {
      setFilterType(value);
      if (value === 'None') {
        setDates([]);
      }

     
    };
    

    const handleFilterTypeChange = (value) => {
            setFilterType(value);
            if (value === 'Custom') {
              setDates([]);
            } else if (value === 'Today') {
              setDates([moment(), moment()]);
            } else if (value === 'Yesterday') {
              setDates([moment().subtract(1, 'day'), moment()]);
            } else if (value === 'Last 7 Days') {
              setDates([moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()]);
            } else if (value === 'Last 30 Days') {
              setDates([moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()]);
            } else if (value === 'Last 90 Days') {
              setDates([moment().subtract(89, 'days'), moment()]);
            } else if (value === 'Last 180 Days') {
              setDates([moment().subtract(179, 'days'), moment()]);
            } else if (value === 'Last 365 Days') {
              setDates([moment().subtract(364, 'days'), moment()]);
          }
          };
      const handleDatePickerOpenChange = (status: any) => {
            if (status) {
              setFilterType('Custom');
            }
          };
    
console.log(dates[0])
console.log(dates[1])

return (
  <div style={{ margin: 20 }}>
    <label>Filter Type:</label>
    <Select
      defaultValue={filterType}
      placeholder='Select Date'
      style={{ width: '250px', marginLeft: '10px' }}
      onChange={handleFilterType}>
      <Option value="None">None</Option>
      <Option value="Date Range">Date Range</Option>
    </Select>

    <br/><br/>
    <label style={{ display: "block" }}>Default Configuration:</label>
    <div style={{ display: "inline-flex" ,marginTop: '10px'}}>
      <Select value={dateRange} onChange={handleFilterTypeChange} 
              placeholder='---- Select Condition ----' 
              style={{ width: '260px', marginRight: '10px' }} 
              disabled={filterType == "None"}
              >
        <Option value="Custom">Custom</Option>
        <Option value="Today">Today</Option>
        <Option value="Yesterday">Yesterday</Option>
        <Option value="Last 7 Days">Last 7 Days</Option>
        <Option value="Last 30 Days">Last 30 Days</Option>
        <Option value="Last 90 Days">Last 90 Days</Option>
        <Option value="Last 180 Days">Last 180 Days</Option>
        <Option value="Last 365 Days">Last 365 Days</Option>
      </Select>

      <div style={{ display: "inline-flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <div style={{ marginRight: '10px' }}>
          <DatePicker
            value={dates.length > 0 ? moment(dates[0]) : null}
            disabled={filterType == "None"}
            style={{ width: '280px' ,verticalAlign: "middle"}}
            onOpenChange={handleDatePickerOpenChange}
          />

        </div>
        <div>
          <label style={{  verticalAlign: "middle" }}>to &nbsp;</label>
          <DatePicker
            value={dates.length > 0 ? moment(dates[1]) : null}
            disabled={filterType == "None"}
            style={{ width: '280px' ,verticalAlign: "middle"}}
            onOpenChange={handleDatePickerOpenChange}
          />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
  }

export default Filter;
```

if i click on the Date range option its shows date ranges like today, yesterday,last 7 days etc...
all date ranges are working if try to click on the date manually once i selected the date range the dates are going infinity and keep going how to solve this issue?

if i click on the Date range option its shows date ranges like today, yesterday,last 7 days etc...
all date ranges are working if try to click on the date manually once i selected the date range the dates are going infinity and keep going how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please proofread your post and improve capitalization and punctuation. Your run-together sentences make you difficult to understand. Put the same effort into your English that you put into your code.